# Can a PCI-X card be used in a PCI-E slot?

Tags: pci-express, pci-x

Does anyone know if a PCI-X card can be used in a PCI-E slot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, i believe you can use PCI in [PCI-X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI-X) (but not vice versa) since PCI-X is a extension to the PCI protocol. The only slot that a PCI-X card will work with is a PCI X slot

PCI-E is a whole different distinct protocol despite the name and is [electrically and physically incompatible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI-X#Confusion_with_PCI-Express) - the card definitely won't fit by design, and almost everything is different between PCI/PCI-X and PCI-E

It almost absolutely will *not* work

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Journeyman Geek has rightly said.

You can still use a riser card implementation which will provide with a proper PCI-X to PCIe bridge.  One such option is [this](http://www.plxtech.com/files/pdf/apps/ExpApp51_Riser_card.pdf)